# Custom Windows not rendering properly after upgrading to 2.0.12 in angular-google-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, coffeescript, angular-google-maps

I have recently upgraded angular-google-maps to 2.0.12 and my custom template(for window) is not loading when I click the marker. It used to work fine before. I have referred all the documentation and changelog but of no avail(which is how I made the markers work at the first place). Can someone help me fix this.

Here is my haml view:

```
%ui-gmap-google-map(center='map.center' pan='map.pan' options='map.options' draggable='true' zoom='map.zoom')
  %ui-gmap-markers(models='map.markers' icon="'icon'" coords="'self'" click="'click'" events="'events'")
    %ui-gmap-windows(show="'showWindow'" closeClick="'closeClick'" isIconVisibleOnClick="'isIconVisibleOnClick'" options='map.infoWindowCustomClass.options' templateUrl="'templateUrl'" templateParameter="'templateParameter'")
```

And here is my coffeescript code where I push the markers model:

```
$scope.map.markers.push
                id:index
                icon:'images/ignore/marker.png'
                latitude: latlongs[index].latitude
                longitude: latlongs[index].longitude
                showWindow:false,
                templateUrl:'views/maptooltip.html'
                appName:latlongs[index].app
                userName:latlongs[index].usr
                city:latlongs[index].city
                country:latlongs[index].country
                click:()->
                  $scope.map = mapSettings.setMapCenter({
                      latitude:this.model.latitude-30
                      longitude:0
                    })
                  this.model.showWindow = true
                  this.model.templateParameter={}
                  this.model.templateParameter.appName = this.model.appName;
                  this.model.templateParameter.userName = this.model.userName;
                  this.model.templateParameter.city = this.model.city;
                  this.model.templateParameter.country = this.model.country;
                  $scope.$apply()
                closeClick:()->
                  this.model.showWindow = false
                  $scope.$apply()
```

And here is my map Object:

```
      zoom: 2
      pan:true
      center: 
        latitude: 40
        longitude: 0
      infoWindowCustomClass:
        options:
          boxClass:'dashboard-new-tooltip'
      options:
          minZoom:2
          maxZoom:11
          disableDefaultUI:true
          styles:[{
                    "featureType": "water",
                    "stylers": [
                      { "color": "#1B2028" }
                    ]
                  },{
                    "featureType": "poi",
                    "stylers": [
                      { "visibility": "off" }
                    ]
                  },{
                    "featureType": "road",
                    "stylers": [
                      { "visibility": "off" }
                    ]
                  }
                  ,{
                    "elementType": "labels",
                    "stylers": [
                      { "visibility": "off" }
                    ]
                  },{
                    "featureType": "transit",
                    "elementType": "all",
                    "stylers": [
                      { "visibility": "off" }
                    ]
                  },{
                    "featureType": "administrative",
                    "stylers": [
                      { "visibility": "off" }
                    ]
                  },{
                    "featureType": "landscape",
                    "stylers": [
                      { "color": "#4e555f" }
                    ]
                  }]
```

Comment: Okay. I just realised that the template is loading but the custom class is not getting added. Any ideas why?

Comment: I have raised a bug with nmccready regarding this. Interested people can follow the conversation [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1077)